# Convert virtualenv instance/`requirements.txt` to pipenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I've got a lot of projects using the `virtualenv` and `requirements.txt` or `./requirements/` pattern, but now using `pipenv` is obviously many times superior.

It seems to be easy to generate `requirements.txt` from `pipenv`, but going the other way seems more confusing.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to "convert" existing projects to `pipenv`.

I'm writing a script to execute `pipenv` on everything in a large `requirements.txt` but this can't be right -- is there a way to apply an existing requirements.txt to a `pipenv`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I figured out to answer my own question and think there's potential for an "official"/detailed way of doing this:

```
$ pipenv shell
(env) $ pip install -r requirements
```

Also this exists now: https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt

```
$ pipenv install -r path/to/requirements.txt
```

Really I'd just misunderstood the levels of abstraction of `pipenv`.